# How to deal with a skewed Time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I have hourly data of no. of minutes spent online by people for 2 years. Hence the values are distributed between 0 and 60 and also most data is either 0 or 60. My goal is to predict the number of minutes the person will spend online in the future (next day/hour/month etc.). What kind of approach or machine learning model can I use to predict this data? Can this be modelled into a regression/forecasting problem in spite of the skewness?[hourly data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk93I.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to make the question more specific (at present it is very broad). More information about the data would also make it easier for people to respond.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of time series data and its prediction, it’s better to use a regression model rather than a classification or clustering model. Because it’s related to calculating specific figures.

It can be modeled into a regression problem to some extent, but more skewness means getting far from the normal probability distribution which might influence the expression into the model, lower prediction accuracy, and so forth. Anyway, any data with significant skewness cannot be regarded as well-refined data. So you might need to rearrange the samples of the data so that the skewness of the data can decrease.